# Trying to filter the options for a dropdown based on first dropdown selection from same table

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a MySQL database I created that creates 2 dropdowns to filter the agents by locations:

```
Agent | Location
Steve | Florida
Robert| New York
Joe   | New York
```

Dropdown 1: Location

Dropdown 2: All of the agents in location selected in dropdown 1

I have been trying every Google and Stackoverflow suggestion but nothing is doing what I need. Figured this was kinda of simple. I would appreciate any help. I am getting the data I need but I cannot get it to fill in a dropdown. It creates a dropdown for each option.

```
<?php
include 'DBController.php';
$db_handle = new DBController();
$element_5Result = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT element_5 FROM providers ORDER BY element_5 ASC");
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="search" action="index.php">
        <select id="Place" name="element_5[]" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Select element_5</option>
            <?php
            if (! empty($element_5Result)) {
                foreach ($element_5Result as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $element_5Result[$key]['element_5'] . '">' . $element_5Result[$key]['element_5'] . '</option>';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select><br> <br>
        <button id="Filter">Search</button>
    </div>

    <?php if (! empty($_POST['element_5'])) { ?>
        <select>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * from providers";
        $i = 0;
        $selectedOptionCount = count($_POST['element_5']);
        $selectedOption = "";
        while ($i < $selectedOptionCount) {
            $selectedOption = $selectedOption . "'" . $_POST['element_5'][$i] . "'";
            if ($i < $selectedOptionCount - 1) {
                $selectedOption = $selectedOption . ", ";
            }

            $i ++;
        }
        $query = $query . " WHERE element_5 in (" . $selectedOption . ")";
        $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
    }
    if (! empty($result)) {
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
             if (! empty($result)) {
                foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $result[$key]['element_1'] . '">' . $result[$key]['element_1'] . '</option>';
                }
             }
        ?>
    </select>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far? Without some of your current code it'll be hard to help you.

Comment: What is the problem actually? First thing i see is a invalid nested option construction since you generate `<option>` tags inside another `<option>` tag

Comment: I don't know what I need to do to filter the options for the second dropdown based on the first

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection!  [Use PDO and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example, While i dont have your full code i tried to create an example similar to yours. So please alter my codes according to your field names.
If you have trouble implementing it into your codes tell me

**FIRST** is a query to get your options for the first dropdown and put it into an array

```
$dropdown1 = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT options FROM dropdown1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dropdown1)) {
      $dropdown1array[] = $row['options'];
    
    }
```

**SECOND** Display the elements in your array for your first dropdown and create your second dropdown

```
<form method="POST" >
                <select  name="dropdown1[]" multiple="multiple" size="7">
                    <option value="0" >Select dropdown1</option>
                        <?php
                            foreach ($dropdown1array as $value) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';    }
                         ?>
                </select>
            <select  name="dropdown2" multiple="multiple" size="7">
                    <option value="0" >Select 2</option>
```

**THIRD**

```
<?php
     
    // Check if form is submitted successfully
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        // Check if any option is selected
        if(isset($_POST["dropdown1"]))
        {
            // Retrieving each selected option and putting it into the second dropdown
            foreach ($_POST['dropdown1'] as $dropdown1){
            
                    echo '<option value="' . $dropdown1 . '">' . $dropdown1 . '</option>';  
        }}
        else{
            echo "Select an option first !!";
    }
}
    
?>
```

```
  </select> 
   <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = Submit>    
   </form>
```